# mutableListOf to Bundle (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, bundle, android-dialogfragment, mutablelist

I have a mutableLIst:

```
var books = mutableListOf<Book>()
```

model "Book" is:

```
data class Book(val title: String, val id: Int)
```

My code is:

```
      button2.setOnClickListener{
        val delFragment = DelFragment()
        val booksforDel = Bundle()
        booksforDel.putStringArrayList("books", books as ArrayList<String>)
        delFragment.setArguments(booksforDel)

        val manager = supportFragmentManager
        delFragment.show(manager,"Delete Book")
    }
```

in Fragment I try to get data:

```
val booksForDelete = getArguments()?.getStringArrayList("books")!!
```

And get Error:

> java.lang.ArrayStoreException: source[0] of type com.example.http_example.model.Book cannot be stored in destination array of type java.lang.String[]

How send a data from mutableList "books" to Bundle in DialogFragment?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [`Parcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable) interface:

```
data class Book(val title: String, val id: Int) : Parcelable {
    constructor(source: Parcel) : this(
            source.readString()!!,
            source.readInt()
    )

    override fun describeContents() = 0

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) = with(dest) {
        writeString(title)
        writeInt(id)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmField
        val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<Book> = object : Parcelable.Creator<Book> {
            override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel): Book = Book(source)
            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Book?> = arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like the following:

```
var books = mutableListOf<Book>()
val booksforDel = Bundle()
booksforDel.putParcelableArray("books", books.toTypedArray())
```

Ann to retrieve books in a Fragment:

```
val booksForDelete = arguments?.getParcelableArray("books")
```

Comment: it's work. how to organize setSingleChoiceItems for bookForDelete? I make a code: .setSingleChoiceItems(booksForDelete?.map(Book::title)?.toTypedArray(),checkedItem){
                    dialog, which ->
                    Toast.makeText(activity,"Choosen book: ${booksForDelete?.map { Book::title}?.get(which)}",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                 
                }  IDE marked "map" in the first line

Comment: Please create another question on Stackoverflow and include all information there, give me a link here, and I'll try to help.

Comment: ok. i try. я вам очень признателен за помощь. потому как только осваиваю Kotlin.

Comment: instead of implementing `Parcelable` we can now use `@Parcelize` annotation before the class.